# Error while launching soapUi 3.01

Tags: java, web-services, soapui

soapui.bat
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cl
i/CommandLineParser

Where can I find this library? I already put JAVA HOME to my sdk and I am using windows XP. Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resolved needed to put correct path to jdk 1.6 and soapui in the batch file soapui.bat

Answer (score 3):

it works fine with jdk 1.5. Only things is jar files are not getting added to classpath with ..\lib*

Add below lines in 'soapui.bat' (for windows XP),

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if defined CLASSPATH (set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;.) else (set CLASSPATH=.)
FOR /R ..\lib %%G IN (*.jar) DO set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%G
```

This will append the classpath with all the jars present in ..\lib

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message when trying to run the latest SoapUI 4.5.1. It seems that the links on the SoapUI page are incorrect and I downloaded the zip file that didn't include the Java Runtime. Once I downloaded the "standalone" package that includes the JRE the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have the [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) JAR in your CLASSPATH.  Add it to your Eclipse project and see what the next problem will be.  I'm guessing that you're missing more than one JAR, so you'll have to repeat this until your CLASSPATH issues all go away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `lib` directory inside `SoapUI-5.0.0` didn't had read/chdir permissions for other users. I was installing soapui in a common location outside of `home`.

Permissions were `drwxr-x--- 2 ... lib`

A simple `chmod o+r,o+X lib` was all needed to get it working.